# Textures go missing when I set new scene

Tags: texturing, game-engine, camera, logic-bricks

I have a game menu scene, and when I press start I **set** the new scene to be the main scene.

Problem is, most textures disappear leaving a light purple color behind them (not the default one for missing textures), like this: [image]

In this image for example the ceiling has a texture. What am I missing? It works normally till I set the scene.

Comment: Make sure you're set to GLSL

Comment: Thanks Vincent. Although this one was set to GLSL the previous scene was to multitexture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Viewport Shading**

I think your starting scene is set to "Solid". Ensure it is set "Texture" or "Material".

[image]

**Render tab shading**

One scene might use Shading mode "Multitexture", while the other uses "GLSL". Ensure to use the same mode for all of you scenes.

[image]

Comment: Yeah the game-menu scene was set to multitexture and it changed the glsl to multitexture too, when set. Thanks.

Comment: hey monster, if someone posts the correct answer in the comments, we usually wait for them to answer for 24 hours. if they don't then it's free game.

Comment: This answer was aiming for Shading Mode (the Render tab mode was discovered while reproducing the situation). I'm not sure if I saw your comment at that time, sorry. --- I suggest to post answers as answer (Yes, I do not do this all the time either :D ).